# SassError Can't find stylesheet to import @import "ionic.globals";

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, ionic5, angular10

Trying to update my project from ionic 3 to 5 and when i do ionic serve got this:

```
ERROR in ./src/theme/variables.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--14-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-4!./src/theme/variables.scss)
[ng] Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
[ng] SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
[ng]    ╷
[ng] 15 │ @import "ionic.globals";
[ng]    │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ng]    ╵
[ng]   D:\Producao\Ts-CeoMobile_io5\Ts-CeoMobile\src\theme\variables.scss 15:9  root stylesheet
[ng] ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-node&sockPath=/sockjs-node ./src/main.ts
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\Producao\Ts-CeoMobile_io5\Ts-CeoMobile\src\main.ts' in 'D:\Producao\Ts-CeoMobile_io5\Ts-CeoMobile'
[ng] ERROR in multi ./src/polyfills.ts ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/jit-polyfills.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\Producao\Ts-CeoMobile_io5\Ts-CeoMobile\src\polyfills.ts' in 'D:\Producao\Ts-CeoMobile_io5\Ts-CeoMobile'
[ng] ERROR in Must have a source file to refactor.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
./src/theme/variables.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
[ng] SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
[ng]   ╷
[ng] 5 │ @import "ionic.globals";
[ng]   │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ng]   ╵
[ng]   src/theme/variables.scss 5:9  root stylesheet



solutions:
Added global.scss manually in the project.
Added polyfills.ts manually in the project.
main.ts was misplaced in my project.
All three files should be created or placed in the src folder.
```